Can I reduce contact with my father?
Salam mualaykum !! my question is: can I reduce contact with my father who was never in my life nor did not that do much for me ? He is making me something that could potentially affect my life and my other sibling’s while being really toxic. What can do about that? I’ve been patient with him for years but it is getting out of hand. He doesn’t even care whether I am going through something’s or not . None my other siblings even talks to him but now I am on the edge of doing the same thing but I don’t want to go against sharia . His mental abuse is stressing me out! Please help

This isn't a peer support or fatwa site. Please view https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and also look around for similar questions for before asking your own.

Walaikumussalam. I am a teen and hence do not have enough experience to to empathize or even guide you. But I sympathize with you.
I suggest you reduce contact with him, like you have been willin' to do, but do not end contact with your parents.
Most people after reducing contact with their parents eventually forget them.
Pray to allah ,rest is on you.

Avoid answering off-topic questions, please. View https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
